# How to find which async action triggers ngZone (that lead to Change Detection)?

Tags: angular, debugging, angular-ngzone

Any changes in the stack trace of updates always lead back to `globalZoneAwareCallback`. How do you find out what triggered the change?

In terms of debugging it's good to have a clear picture.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`globalZoneAwareCallback` is a function declared in zonejs for handling all event callbacks with `capture=false`. (btw, for `capture=true` there is `globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback`)

It means that any event listener will first go through this method. That listener can be added on the page by Angular, by you or by any 3rd party library.

There are many ways of how we can listen to browser events in Angular:

- subscribe to browser event `<element (event)="callback()">`
- `@HostListener` decorator `@HostListener('event') callback() {}`
- `Renderer2.listen` method
- rxjs `fromEvent`
- assign element property `element.on<event> = callback`
- addEventListener method `element.addEventListener(event, callback)`(this method is used internally in many other ways above)

Once you're within `globalZoneAwareCallback` you have access to all **Zone tasks** that should be triggered.

Let's imagine we listen to `click` event on `document.body`:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
   // some code
});
```

Let's open Chrome dev tools to have a clear picture:

[image]

What we've just discovered:

- each Zone task contain **source** so this is what triggers the change
- **target** property shows which object triggers the change
- **callback** property can lead us to the handler of the change

Let's consider another example and add click event using Angular way:

```
<h2 class="title" (click)="test()">Hello {{name}}</h2>
```

Once we click on that `h2` element we should observe the following:

[image]

You might be surprised that now **callback** property didn't bring us to the `test` callback right away but rather we showed some wrapper from `@angular/platform-browser package`. And other cases also may differ but **ZoneTask.source** property is usually all you need in those cases because it **shows** you **the root cause of the change**.